# When use Fetch API in react web

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch

I'm using fetch api in my react project.

When fetch was in each components, it works right
but making fetch function in lib.js, it doesn't work now.

before lib.js (it works)

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch(url, {
    method: options.method || 'GET',
    headers,
    cache: 'default',
    body: options.body ? JSON.stringify(options.body) : undefined,
    mode: 'cors',
  }).then((res) => {
    if (res.ok) {
      return res.json()
    } else {
      console.log('err');
  }).then(data => {
    console.log(data); // it logs right data
    return data;
  })
```

after lib.js (it's not works)

```
export function myRequest(url) {
  fetch(url, {
    method: options.method || 'GET',
    headers,
    cache: 'default',
    body: options.body ? JSON.stringify(options.body) : undefined,
    mode: 'cors',
  }).then((res) => {
    if (res.ok) {
      return res.json()
    } else {
      console.log('err');
  }).then(data => {
    return data;
  })
}
```

react component

```
getData() {
  return Promise.resolve(lib.myRequest('url'))
   .then(a => console.log(a)); // it logged undefined
}
```

I don't know what is my mistake.

how to use imported fetch api?

Comment: `myRequest` doesn't return anything ... so of course it logs undefined

Comment: @abdul edited my code. it's just missded

Comment: @JaromandaX Wow thanks very very much. return fetch()~~~~ is correct answer. thanks again.

Comment: do you understand that `console.log(lib.myRequest(url));` will log a Promise, not a value, right

Comment: no need to `Promise.resolve` the promise.  Just chain the `then` directly.